# How to send play store link using facebook share dialog in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sharing a post on facebook using facebook sdk's `WebDialog`(ShareDialog) through which I'm sending these post parameter:  *name, caption, description, link, picture* but i also want to send an additional **link** which is play store link to my app.

I also read the concept of deep linking but that is not in  my requirement. I just want to simply display a play store link to my app through which user can browse and download my app directly.

How can I do that? please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want share only detail to facebook, you have to use this code onClick of share button.

```
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");    
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "ANDROID");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "LINK OF APP ON PLAYSTORE");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
```

Check it.

Comment: Hi shane i am not using intent to share a facebook post i am using WebDialog mentioned in this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share can you suggest some other method according to WebDialog?.